# Laravel - Update Content Error Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

Hello I have an error here saying:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   No message

when I update the content. I have a one image and one view to update.

Below is my view. There is where the content is coded. I have the submit button here which will trigger the update. and the form `@update`.

**admin/airlineplus/paxsafety.blade.php**

```html
    {!! Form::open(['action'=>['Admin\PaxSafetyController@update', $paxsafe->id], 'method' => 'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
<div class="form-group">   
    <div class="table-responsive">  
        <table class="table table-bordered">  

           <tr>  
                     <th>Upload new Image and Video</th>

                     <td>  {{ Form::file('paxsafety_image[]') }} &nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>{{ $paxsafe->paxsafety_image }}&nbsp;&nbsp; </strong> </td> 

                     <td>    {{ Form::file('paxsafety_video[]') }} &nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>{{ $paxsafe->paxsafety_video }}&nbsp;&nbsp; </strong></td>


              </td>
           </tr>  
        </table><br><br>  
        {{Form::submit('submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'name'=>'submit'])}}
    </div> 
</div>  
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Next, my controller.

**MyCoolController.php**

```php
  $this->validate($request, [
        'paxsafety_image' => 'required',
        'paxsafety_video' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($request->has('paxsafety_image') && $request->has('paxsafety_video'))
    {   
        //Handle File Upload

        $paxSafety = [];
        foreach ($request->file('paxsafety_image') as $key => $file)
        {
            // Get FileName
            $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just extension
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to Store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file->storeAs('public/paxsafety_folder',$fileNameToStore);
            array_push($paxSafety, $fileNameToStore);
        }


        $paxSafetyVideo = [];
        foreach ($request->file('paxsafety_video') as $key => $file)
        {
            // Get FileName
            $filenameWithExt2 = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt2, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just extension
            $extension2 = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to Store
            $fileNameToStore2 = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension2;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file->storeAs('public/paxsafety_folder',$fileNameToStore2);
            array_push($paxSafetyVideo, $fileNameToStore2);
        }


        $fileNameToStore = serialize($paxSafety);
        $fileNameToStore2 = serialize($paxSafetyVideo);
    }


    foreach ($paxSafety as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($paxSafetyVideo as $key => $values) {
        $paxsafe = PaxSafety::find($id);
        if($request->hasFile('paxsafety_image')){
        $paxsafe->paxsafety_image = $value;
        }
        if($request->hasFile('paxsafety_video')){
        $paxsafe->paxsafety_video = $values;
        }
        $paxsafe->save();
        }
    }
    return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/paxsafety')->with('success', 'Inflight Magazine Content Inserted');
```

Guide me pls im new to coding in Laravel

Comment: you seem to have missed out the start of the controller code? Anyway a "Method not allowed" exception in HTTP means that the HTTP method you used to make the request is not permitted by the server to be used at the URL you sent it to. e.g. your form submits using the HTTP "POST" method, but perhaps you didn't set your action method up to accept POST requests. Maybe it only accepts GET or something.

Comment: Hi Summer Can you please post your route that points to the Method for processing this?

Comment: Hi @Josh here is my route Route::resource('/admin/airlineplus/paxsafety', 'Admin\PaxSafetyController');

Comment: It works on insert ... but when I update it the error occurs

Comment: I've solved the problem..I forgot to put csrf or PUT method above the submit button :;) LOL thank you for the HTTP

Answer (score 2):

the verb that listens to your function is a ***PUT*** and in your code you use the verb **POST**
to solve your probleme add 
*{{ Form::hidden('_method','PUT') }}*
in your form